# how to perform operation after successfully starting elastic search

Tags: bash, shell, elasticsearch

I have to create a shell script to start elastic search from shell command and after successful start of elastic search I have to perform certain operation.
In my case elastic search is starts but after that nothing happens not even echo command works.

Here is the code sample :

```
elasticsearch-1.7.2/bin/elasticsearch   

res=$( curl -w %{http_code} -s --output /dev/null http://localhost:9200)
if [ $res -eq 200 ]
then 
        echo "Elastic search running successfully"  
        Perform operation
fi
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

A shell script executes 1 line at time and doesn't move onto the next line (command) until the current one has completed.

You can use the `&` char to run a command in the background, then the remaining commands can be executed in sequence.

Something like

```
#!/bin/bash
elasticsearch-1.7.2/bin/elasticsearch &

/bin/sleep 30 # change to num secs needed for ES to start correctly

res=$( curl -w %{http_code} -s --output /dev/null http://localhost:9200)
if [ $res -eq 200 ]
then 
        echo "Elastic search running successfully"  
        Perform operation
fi
```

might help.