# Regarding operation flow in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, command

I was just wondering, in a bash script, if I have a command on one line to say rsync a large file (~10GB) then the next command on the next line is meant to rename then move that same file, will the script know to wait for the rsync to complete before attempting the rename and move?

Is there a flag or something I can put on each line to make it wait before executing the next command?

Sorry if this seems like a total noob question, but alas I am a noob!

Thanks in advance for any info!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229567/how-to-perform-operation-after-successfully-starting-elastic-search/34229828#34229828 is an illustrative answer. Substitute elasticsearch with `rsync` and you'll be up to speed. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All commands are executed in sequence, so, a command will wait for the previous command to complete. Only when you add a `&` to the end of a command will it run in the background, and thus *not* wait for completion before executing the next.